# How two save some fields of a model in other model at the same time

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model:

```
class Match2x1(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(League)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    team_a = models.ForeignKey(Teams)
    team_b = models.ForeignKey(Teams,related_name="equipos")
    ending_hour = models.TimeField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        match = "%s VS %s"%(self.team_a,self.team_b)
        return match
```

And i want to save team_a and team_b fields at the same time when i save these model in this model:

```
class TeamsMatch(models.Model):
    team = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on: `same time when i save these model in this model:`? You want to basically save `team_a` and `team_b` when you create a `TeamsMatch` object and save it?

Comment: @LearningNeverStops yes, sorry for my english... i need exactly what you said.

Comment: Then what exactly is `TeamsMatch`? I mean, could you explain the scenario of the save? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @LearningNeverStops as you see, my project is about a soccer match, i need to determine who is the winner, the way how im thinking to do it is save it in other model the teams selected in Match2x1 model and then in other model select who was the winner

Comment: Are you sure you want to go with this model, if you ultimately want to store the result of the match with the team_a or team_b as a winner?

Comment: @LearningNeverStops Yes, i think this is the best way to do it, i dont know if there is a better way. How can i do it as i told in the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74863/discussion-between-dfrojas-and-learningneverstops).

Answer (score 0):

how are you adding that match ? Do you paste text ? Or do you have to pick teams from list ?

You could use:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     team_1 = TeamsMatch(self.team_a)
     team_2 = TeamsMatch(self.team_b)
     team_1.save()
     team_2.save()
     super(Match2x1, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```